# Change guest password using pyvmomi

Tags: python, vmware, pyvmomi

I am using pyVmomi for my automation. Now I am testing a VM, where the SSH is disabled by default, and I must change the password upon the first login:

> You are required to change your password immediately (root enforced)

If I try connecting using pyVmomi's `StartProgramInGuest`, I get `vim.fault.InvalidGuestLogin` exception:

> Failed to authenticate with the guest operating system using the supplied credentials

I am looking for a way to change the default password programmatically, (preferably) using pyVmomi

Comment: As far as looking at the error, it seems a login to a guest error by user or password mistake.
Do you have not wrong with the user and password for a guest?

Comment: The credentials are fine. I think vmware doesn't have this type of an error. It is too specific.

Answer (score 0):

To start off, it seems like you failed to pass the correct credentials when calling the "StartProgramInGuest" function, you can specify and pass credentials to this function using  [Name-Password authentication](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/fe08899f-1eec-4d8d-b3bc-a6664c168c2c/7fdf97a1-4c0d-4be0-9d43-2ceebbc174d9/doc/vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication.html), like below.

```
creds = vim.vm.guest.NamePasswordAuthentication(username='username', password='password)
```

Test this and make sure you successfully authenticated to the guest virtual machine. After you're able to successfully authenticate, you can use [Process Manager](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b525fb12-61bb-4ede-b9e3-c4a1f8171510/99ba073a-60e9-4933-8690-149860ce8754/doc/vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec.html), to create either a Linux process or Windows process to change your password. For example, here is a PowerShell process tested on a Windows 10 virtual machine, executed through StartProgramInGuest.

```
 argument= vim.vm.guest.ProcessManager.ProgramSpec(programPath='powershell.exe -Command', arguments='"& {net user  loginid  newpassword;}"')
 res = pm.StartProgramInGuest(vm, creds, argument)
```

Let me know if you need any clarification!